# How to add a button next to a firebase dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase

I have a dynamically generated html table using jquery.
code here:

```js
var $ = jQuery;
var database = firebase.database().ref();
database.child('DATA').on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
if (snapshot.exists()) {
 var content = '';
 snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
  var val = data.val();
  console.log(val);
  content += '<tr>';
  content += '<td class="cell100 column1">' + val.date + '</td>';
  content += '<td class="cell100 column2">' + val.time + '</td>';
  content += '<td class="cell100 column3">' + val.temperature + '</td>';
  content += '<td class="cell100 column4">' + val.heartrate + '</td>';
  content += '<td class="cell100 column5" data-col="location">' + val.latitude + ',' + val.longitude + '</td>';
  content += '<td class="cell100 column5"><input  value="get me" type="button" class="theButton" id="ma"></td>';
 }); 
 $('#ex-table').append(content);
}
});
```

I want to be able to get the location data from the table generated here:
[image of the table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWXxv.png).
I can't seem to make it work.
I needed the location data so I can insert it in a google map link redirected for the user when the button beside that certain location is clicked.

A little help will be so much appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
I tried using this code:

```js
$('body').on('click', 'td[data-col]', function() {
  $('#ex-table').data('col', $(this).data('col'));
  alert('Selected Column: ' + $(this).data('col'));
}).on('click', 'input.theButton', function(e) {
  var col,txt;
  col = $('#ex-table').data('col');
  txt = $(this).parent().siblings("td[data-col=" + col + "]").text();
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(txt);
});
```

but I can't seem to find a way to make it work easily for the purpose I wanted.
All it does is, I needed to click first the cell of the location I wanted to get, then click the get me button beside it. Then an alert popups with the location data that I have grabbed.

I do not know how to make it work for the purpose I needed. I badly need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a data on your button id then try using this

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.theButton', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```